# Simulating Layers with Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I tried similating layers with overlapping HTML5 canvas but that doesn't appear to work. The 1st canvas defined in HTML will get all the events, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove.

http://jsbin.com/ewival/edit#preview

Is it possible to simulate layeys with canvas? So that I can work with layers/canvas independently?

Comment: Sounds like you want the click-through property thing. IIRC that's not very well supported yet though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to always keep 100% of the event handlers on the topmost canvas, and have those events consider each canvas in order.

So there will only be one mousedown, etc, and it will look through your list of canvases doing the relevant things (hit detection, etc). Assuming your canvases are directly over each other, there will be no coordinate issues.

Comment: Thanks it works http://jsfiddle.net/EWJKw/1/, I used a listener div positioned above the canvas-es.